# How can i add another one route in this code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

i need to add admin user. I read that i need to separate routes in my app.js file. But i can't find example that i need to done this. May be someone can help me to fix this problem ?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/admin', {
                controller: 'AdminController',
                templateUrl: 'admin/admin.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand something correctly as I'm just learning, but the question is this. Can I add to this file a separate route for the administrator so that only the administrator can see the admin page?

Comment: you could add a restriction in the `angular.config` with `data: {authorisedRoles:[USER_ROLES.admin]}`, which can be checked in the `angular.run` with `if (next.data.authorisedRoles) {...}`. Here is a [detailed guide](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec) about it

Comment: I think you just need to copy a `.when()` block and set the values you need.

Comment: I need to create pages that only the admin can see. The option to copy a block will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mekhami/359adacab80c6f0d824e)

Basically what you need is attach some restriction related data to your route and check on page transition if you are authorized and redirect if not.

Dedicated AuthService can contain currentUser and authorization data instead of chaotic data in the run block.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look at this.

Comment: i'm glad it helped